# PHP: chmod folder privileges

Tags: php, mkdir

I've got a couple of short questions about chmod/mkdir functions on PHP. I've been reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php and got confused with chmod.

1. What is the meaning of second number(7) on chmod("...", 0700), as I
   understand only owner can do stuff anything with the files, but what
   exactly is this owner? I mean is it PHP script or is it me typing in
   URL that exact file with its location?How does it even recognize
   "owner"?
2. If for example I make a folder this way:

   mkdir('user_files/'.$logged_username.'/', 0700);

and then I'd put some files in that $logged_username folder, are the files removable by anyone?

Hope these questions even make sense...Thanks for your time.

Comment: The user refers to the operating system's user. For example, php is commonly run through the web server apache's processes, which in turn are run as the user "www" (differs between OSes). If you have a linux server you can check out the permissions and the owner with `ls -l <file>`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions is a non-friendly but pretty complete resource.

Comment: chmod is done octal. The first zero means it an octal number. The `7` is a decimal representation of (bin)`111` this means the owner has read, write and execute permisions. (r=1, wr=1, x=1). If u want to allow group to read the file it be would r=1 w= 0 and x= 0 meaning this would be `4` (0740)

Answer (score 0):

Below a simple explaination of that number

The octal (0-7) value is calculated by adding the values for each digit for each type of permission

example

```
Owner/User (rwx) = 4+2+1 = 7
Group(rwx) = 4+2+1 = 7
World (rx) = 4+1 = 5
chmode mode = 0755
```

where

```
r = read
w = write
x = execution
```

In your particular case the owner is the owner of the file, you could change with chown command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every file in the operating system has a owner. Generally the owner is the one who created that file. However, the ownership of the file can be changed later (e.g. via chown command in Unix). In the context of your question '0700' means that owner has all the rights. This owner means the legitimate owner in the operating system, not the person accessing the URL via browser.
2. If you make a folder in that way, the owner of that folder will be the user that runs that specific PHP script in the web server. Often times this is the same user under whom the web server is running (but not always - e.g. when PHP is run under a separate user via FPM etc.) This means any subsequent PHP program running under the same user will be able to have full access to those files.